Copy range and format from excel and paste into new word doc
I need to have a button with a macro that copies a range of cells and their formatting/make it autofit width wise on an doc and pasted them into a new word document when the button is clicked.
This is what I have. It doesn’t do anything. Not even showing an error.
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()
On Error GoTo ClearError
   
    Const wdFolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const wdFileName As String = "Test.docx"
   
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
   
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Format")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("B29:B119")
   
    ' Reference the Word Application.
   
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordWasClosed As Boolean
   
    ' 1. Attempt to create a reference (check if it is open).
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo ClearError
   
    ' 2. If no reference, open and create a reference to it.
    If wdApp Is Nothing Then ' Word is closed
        Set wdApp = New Word.Application
        WordWasClosed = True
        wdApp.Visible = True ' uncomment when done testing
    'Else ' Word is open and referenced; do nothing
    End If
   
    ' Open and reference a new word document.
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document: Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
   
    ' Copy/Paste.
    rg.Copy
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=True, _
        RTF:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   
    ' Continue modifying the Word document...
   
    
SafeExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        ' Save and close the Word document.
        If Not wdDoc Is Nothing Then ' overwrite without confirmation
            wdDoc.SaveAs2 wdFolderPath & wdFileName, wdFormatDocumentDefault
        End If
        ' Quit the Word application...
        If WordWasClosed Then ' ... if it initially was closed
            If Not wdApp Is Nothing Then wdApp.Quit
        'Else ' ... if it initially was open, don't quit; do nothing
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
   
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub

